# Javascript - Best way to append large amount of HTML content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xml

**Requirement:**

I'm building a simple web application with the requirement of having a single page, and never having the page reload at all. I was once told never to authenticate anything serious client side (javascript), and I'm sticking to this; I'm using AJAX with PHP to authenticate everything server side. There just aren't going to be any page reloads / actual form submissions. It's all 100% dynamic with AJAX linking my client-side script with the server-side PHP. So to the question:

*Without these requirement's, I'd simply throw in a PHP include on the page reload.*

**My question:**

What's the best way to append a large amount of HTML to the document after the user has logged in successfully?

*.append() (Jquery) is a fair enough way, but I'm wondering if there's something more efficient, that will allow me to load in the body of this application without having to stuff it into .append([all of that html in here]).*

**Alternatives?**

- Maybe I could load an XML file holding the HTML data with javascript/AJAX rather than throwing the whole HTML body structure of my page into my script?
- Maybe I can grab a plain HTML or text file with javascript and append the data that way?

Any method that would allow developers to keep scripts clean would be very helpful. Even when appending a simple, small html module of some sort, a message element in a web application for example, placing all of that HTML into the javascript feels messy and unprofessional. I'd much prefer to be able to call on the HTML data from a separate file and append it as a variable.

Comment: Have you considered using something like Backbone or Ember.js?

You could easily set up an Ember.js template and populate/update it with AJAX responses. This might be a more structured way of doing things. For example, in a project of mine I'm using ember.js along side socket.io to populate/update the template in realtime.

Comment: That's interesting, I've just begun learning about Socket.io, it's a powerful tool, but I haven't seen Ember.js; I'm looking into that library now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of appending, I would suggest having a container element, then doing `$('#container').html(ajaxResponseBody)`. This way it is nicely accessible, safely contained and easy to delete or replace.

Comment: But it takes time if the response is large DOM in IE browser. I faced issue with it specifically in IE9 and IE11.

Answer (score -1):

There are particularly to types of **append after** and **before**

http://api.jquery.com/after/

my suggestion to use **insertafter** which is quite good also

http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

**Append** also best to use but its all depends on you what you want to use based on requirement based on choice of **yours all matters**
i hope this will help you regards...:)